# How can I specify child styles with next.js?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

I have:

```
import styles from './Editor.module.css'
...
      <ReactQuill
        theme="bubble"
        value={documentState.content}
        onChange={handleChange}
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        className={styles.quill}
      />
```

Where `Editor.module.css` is:

```
.quill {
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.quill  .ql-container {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

So the `.quill` style gets properly applied. But the child element `.ql-container` does not.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how did you conclude from the screenshot that the style is being applied to .quill?

Comment: Because of `Editor_quill__2D7K2`

Comment: You can target a global class using the `:global` selector in your CSS Module file, e.g. `.quill  :global(.ql-container) { position: absolute !important; }`. See [How to override global CSS in a CSS module file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217278/how-to-override-global-css-in-a-css-module-file).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't target sub-components in css modules via classnames. You can, however, target them via other selectors.

So you could do something like:

```
.quill > div:first-child {
  // styles
}
```

to target the `ql-container` div.

Alternatively, you can create a global style sheet to target `.ql-container`.

Comment: I suppose I might have to create a global stylesheet

Comment: Be sure to change the `div` in `div:first-child` to match the HTML tag type (i.e., div, input, span) of the child element you are looking to select.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same situation and came up with the `[class*=className]` solution.

In your case:

```
.quill [class*=ql-container] {
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

This will find children that have a partially matched class of ql-container.

You could also use the `[class$=className]` or `[class^=className]` selectors to get the 'starts-with' and 'ends-with' matches. The 'ends-with' selector will not style child classes that have similar class names. E.g. `control-prev` and `control-prev-icon`

Answer (score 1):

like @[juliomalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870780/juliomalves)  say in the comment, I tried and it works well:

in xxx.module.css

```
.card li:global(.list-indent-1) {
    margin-left: 0em;
}
.card li:global(.list-indent-2) {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

in jsx

```
import styles from "./xxx.module.css"

<div class={styles.card}>
<ul>
<li class='list-indent-1'></li>
<li class='list-indent-2'></li>
</ul>
</div>
```