# How to override global CSS in a CSS module file?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-modules

Lets say in my `global.css` file of a Next.js project I have:

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I also have a `Layout.js` component and a `Layout.module.css` file. The component looks like this:

```
import styles from "../styles/Layout.module.css";
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.navbar}>
        <div className="flex">
        <h1>Structured Safety</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Demo</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

and the `Layout.module.css` is:

```
/* Navbar */
.navbar {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .flex {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Structured like this, my `.navbar .flex` does not overwrite the global `.flex` class and split the `h1` from the `nav`. How can I accomplish overwriting my global style from this component style?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since `.flex` refers to a global class you'll need to use the `:global` selector to target it in your CSS module.

```css
/* Layout.module.css */

.navbar :global(.flex) {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Or using an alternate syntax.

```css
.navbar {
    :global {
        .flex {
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/** CSS MODULE FILE **/

```
.classname :global(.globalClass) { css properties }

.classname {
 :global {
  .globalClass { css properties }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In NextJS and React when you
`import styles from "__.css"` the `styles` becomes a variable so you have to use it in your HTML for it to take effect.

Currently you're not using any styles from your Layout.module.css, if you want to use that css you would change your html to: `<div className={styles.navbar}>` and such..

Comment: Or you can just do `import "../styles/Layout.module.css";`

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question to fix my typo. I am using the styles.navbar on the outer div. So I would think that the .navbar .flex selector would correctly select here and change justify-content to space between but that does not happen.