# Next js - how to override style in scss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm using `react-simple-keyboard` and I try to override below style from this library
[image]

by using scss

keyboard.module.scss

```
.react-simple-keyboard{
  width: 50% !important;
}
```

components/keyboard/index.js

```
import keyboardStyle from "./keyboard.module.scss";
...
// Do something using keyboardStyle
```

However, I've found there's no update on the style.

I've tried something like

```
.react-simple-keyboard :global{
  width: 50% !important;
}
```

but still not working
How can I do it?

Comment: Go the the `node_modules` and find `react-simple-keyboard` and there find `scss` or `css` files, Maybe you can override or change styles from there.

Comment: Try using `.keyboard :global(.react-simple-keyboard) { width: 50% !important; }`, and apply `styles.keyboard` to a parent of the `react-simple-keyboard` in your component. See [How to override global CSS in a CSS module file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270281/1870780).