# SASS not working properly within Next.JS CSS modules

Tags: javascript, css, sass, next.js

For the first time, I'm using Next.JS's CSS modules, and they are very useful.

But I'm experiencing a strange behaviour when trying to apply styles to children elements.

For example, if I have the following HTML

```html
<Offcanvas show={menu} onHide={closeMenu} className={styles.mobile_menu}>
    <Offcanvas.Header closeButton className={styles.mobile_menu_header}>
        <Offcanvas.Title className={styles.mobile_menu_title}>
            <h1>Menu</h1>
        </Offcanvas.Title>
    </Offcanvas.Header>
    <Offcanvas.Body>
        <ul className="list-unstyled">
            { links.map((link, key) => (
                <li key={"nav-link-" + key} className="mb-3">
                    <Link href={link.href} className={[styles.link, router.pathname == link.href ? "active" : ""].join(" ")}>{ link.label }</Link>
                </li>
            )) }
        </ul>
    </Offcanvas.Body>
</Offcanvas>
```

And this SCSS

```scss
.mobile_menu {
    background-color: rgb(57, 70, 78) !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.mobile_menu_header {
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(148, 162, 170);

    button.btn-close {
        filter: brightness(0) invert(1) !important;
        opacity: 1 !important;
        width: 1.6rem !important;
        height: 1.6rem !important;
        background-size: 100% !important;
    }
}

.mobile_menu_title {
    h1 {
        font-size: 3.2rem;
    }
}

.link {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;

    &.active {
        border-bottom: solid 1rem rgb(148, 162, 170) !important;
    }

    &:hover {
        color: rgb(148, 162, 170);
    }
}
```

The properties applyed to the `button.btn-close` (that's auto generated by adding the `closeButton` flag to `Offcanvas.Header`) aren't applyed, also links with `active` class hasn't a bottom border as expected.

So this makes me think the SASS in Next.JS's CSS modules aren't using nested/child/ selectors. But, for some reason, the `h1` inside `.mobile_menu_title` is styled, and, when I try to remove the `.btn-close` from selector (leaving only the `button`), it's applied!

So, is this a bug or something I don't know about? Nested styles using SASS only work with "pure" elements, not to selectors that have classes/IDs.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

**Note:** I'm using react-bootstrap package.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you're trying to target global class names in your CSS Modules file. You have to use `:global` selector for that, e.g. `button:global(.btn-close) { ... }`. See [How to override global CSS in a CSS module file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217278/how-to-override-global-css-in-a-css-module-file). As for the active style, you need to use `styles.active` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can do is the following

In your JavaScript file

```
...

<Offcanvas.Header closeButton className={styles.mobile_menu_header}>

  ...

</Offcanvas.Header>

...
```

In your style file

```
.mobile_menu_header {
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(148, 162, 170);
  :global {
    button.btn-close {
      filter: brightness(0) invert(1) !important;
      opacity: 1 !important;
      width: 1.6rem !important;
      height: 1.6rem !important;
      background-size: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}
```

**Why this?**

By adding the `:global` rule, you are, basically, telling your React application: "In the element with **computed** class name `mobile_menu_header` (the actual class name will be like `index_mobile_menu_header_xxxxxxxx`), find the element with class name `btn-close` and apply the style specified".

Wrapping everything in a `mobile_menu_header`, as you did, can be helpful to avoid overwriting `btn-close` in the whole application and have them just overwritten in this component.

This can be a strategy to adapt when the only way to overwrite a CSS library is to overwrite the styles themself (so if you can not customize the library in other ways like styled-components or theme settings) but you also need to face with CSS modules (the one that are causing the name to be like  instead of just the class name).

Answer (score 0):

You can always NOT use modules. Just use classic

```
import  './page.sass'
```

then you can use classic Sass
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-modules